# ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero when doing pairwise comparison of empty lists in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am doing pairwise comparisons on pairs of lists to get the Jaccard similarity. The error message appears when they are pairs of empty lists being compared like the following dataframe.

```
data = {"wordings": [['apple','banana','orange','pears'], ['apple', 'banana'], [], [], []], "users": ['adeline', 'adeline', 'kenzi', 'ericko', 'mary'], "phase":[1, 3, 2, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
# create list of tuples like [(wording, user), (wording, user)]
# copied from OP above
def jaccard_similarity(x, y):
    """ returns the jaccard similarity between two lists """
    intersection_cardinality = len(set.intersection(*[set(x), set(y)]))
    union_cardinality = len(set.union(*[set(x), set(y)]))
    return intersection_cardinality/float(union_cardinality)

wordings_users = list(zip(data["wordings"], data["users"], data["phase"]))

result = []

# create list of all possible combinations between sets of (wording, user) and loop through them
for item in list(itertools.combinations(wordings_users, 2)):
    similarity = jaccard_similarity(item[0][0], item[1][0])
    data = {"user1": item[0][1], "user2": item[1][1], "user1_phase": item[0][2], "user2_phase": item[1][2], "similarity": similarity}
    result.append(data)
print(result)
```

Error Message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/gf/pvtbdsj96cz1tv7vmn1gq7j40000gn/T/ipykernel_74540/2179214669.py in <module>
     13 # create list of all possible combinations between sets of (wording, user) and loop through them
     14 for item in list(itertools.combinations(wordings_users, 2)):
---> 15     similarity = jaccard_similarity(item[0][0], item[1][0])
     16     data = {"user1": item[0][1], "user2": item[1][1], "user1_phase": item[0][2], "user2_phase": item[1][2], "similarity": similarity}
     17     result.append(data)

/var/folders/gf/pvtbdsj96cz1tv7vmn1gq7j40000gn/T/ipykernel_74540/2179214669.py in jaccard_similarity(x, y)
      5     intersection_cardinality = len(set.intersection(*[set(x), set(y)]))
      6     union_cardinality = len(set.union(*[set(x), set(y)]))
----> 7     return intersection_cardinality/float(union_cardinality)
      8 
      9 wordings_users = list(zip(data["wordings"], data["users"], data["phase"]))

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

When the lists are not empty like the following, I don't get the error message, but when pairs of lists are empty, I get the error message.

```
data = {"wordings": [['apple','banana','orange','pears'], ['apple', 'banana'], ['apple','jackfruit'], ['banana','jackfruit','berries','apple'], []], "users": ['adeline', 'adeline', 'kenzi', 'ericko', 'mary'], "phase":[1, 3, 2, 2, 3], "group": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

How can I solve this error in the code? Thank you.

Comment: but why are not you removing empty ones?

Comment: @nerd the issue arises as the value of `union_cardinality` is getting 0 for empty lists, just handle the situation by introducing a if condition before the division and setting Jaccard value to `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue solved with

```
if union_cardinality == 0:
        return 0
```